# Other than others, Hilios countdown timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, countdown

Im wondering, if there is such a way, to **edit Hilios countdown** timer described as below:

I've got a function, which works as it should, to counts down time from date (I want to mark, that **I do have several dates** in single view, where timer is used, so I had to go with each function):

```
$('[data-countdown]').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var finalDate = $(this).data('countdown');
    $this.countdown(finalDate, function(event) {
        $this.html(event.strftime('%D days %H:%M:%S'));
    });
});
```

And here comes the problem. As this script works "**staticly**" - what I mean by static - is that it get's the date from html and passes it into the script as the script is loaded.

My application works **dynamically**, so also the date's are changed dynamically.

So the question is: Is there such a way to edit this script, to work with dynamic data - **when some data is updated on the website, it also updates that data in the countdown timer**.

Best regards! PS.

Comment: I think you need to add onchange method in your html.
Reference - https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp

Comment: onChange doesn't works, as it doesn't see change of the html's div value, which contains date: <p class="card-text" data-countdown="{{ $data->expiration }}" onchange="updateTimer()"></p>

Comment: Then where does that value change? You must be getting it from backend/somewhere and then you would be updating it on UI, right?
Can't you call this method to updateDate there?

**Edit**: So there should be pusher event that you are reading on javascript side, you should write such method inside that.

Comment: That's what Im doing. Pusher updates the value of "DATA-COUNTDOWN" attribute inside the html element whenever new data occurs. But the problem is that it looks like the Hilios countdown timer gets the value which appears first, takes that value into some kind of a cache, and ignores newer value if that occurs...

Answer (score 0):

Please check out [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

```js
// Select the node that will be observed for mutations
var targetNode = document.getElementById('some-id');

// Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
var config = {
  attributes: true,
  attributeFilter: ['data-timer'],
  attributeOldValue: true,
};

// Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
var callback = function(mutationsList) {
  for (var mutation of mutationsList) {
    console.log('CHANGED', mutation.oldValue);
  }
};

// Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

// Start observing the target node for configured mutations
observer.observe(targetNode, config);

// Later, you can stop observing
//observer.disconnect();
```

```html
<div id="some-id" data-timer="123">hello</div>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('some-id').setAttribute('data-timer', +new Date())">change</button>
```

Comment: Looks cool, but dates are changed without any button, I am using pusher to push the newest data from database.

Comment: What's "pusher"? Button is given in the example just for demo purposes. You could change the attribute in js via [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)

Comment: Alright, but it looks like a problem with countdown plugin, which caches the date which it get as first, and any other date isn't accepted (just ignored by plugin).